# window.ethereum.request does not exist on type "isMetaMask, on, removeListener"

Tags: metamask, typescript

It might be a pretty simple question for most, but how do I use the request method on window.ethereum if it does not exist? I see all sorts of properties and methods in the metamask docs, but when I go to write the code in VScode I get an error saying there is only 3 properties/methods on window.ethereum.

Is window.ethereum not fully compatible with Typescript, or am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

metamask docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#methods